# How to use XPath function in a XPathExpression instance programatically?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, namespaces

My current program need to use programatically create a XPathExpression instance to apply to XmlDocument. The xpath needs to use some XPath functions like "ends-with". However, I cannot find a way to use "ends-with" in XPath. I

It throw exception like below

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Xml.XPath.XPathException:
>   Namespace Manager or XsltC ontext
>   needed. This query has a prefix,
>   variable, or user-defined function.
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.CompiledXpathExpr.get_QueryTree()
>   at
>   System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Evaluate(XPathExpression
>   expr, XPathNodeIt erator context)
>   at
>   System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Evaluate(XPathExpression
>   expr)

The code is like this:

```
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
                        <myXml xmlns=""http://MyNamespace"" xmlns:fn=""http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions""> 
                        <data>Hello World</data>
                    </myXml>");
    XPathNavigator navigator = xdoc.CreateNavigator();

    XPathExpression xpr;
    xpr = XPathExpression.Compile("fn:ends-with(/myXml/data, 'World')");

    object result = navigator.Evaluate(xpr);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

I tried to change the code to insert XmlNamespaceManager when compiling the expression, like below

```
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
                        <myXml xmlns=""http://MyNamespace"" xmlns:fn=""http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions""> 
                        <data>Hello World</data>
                    </myXml>");
    XPathNavigator navigator = xdoc.CreateNavigator();
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("fn", "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions");

    XPathExpression xpr;
    xpr = XPathExpression.Compile("fn:ends-with(/myXml/data, 'World')", nsmgr);

    object result = navigator.Evaluate(xpr);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

It fails on XPathExpression.Compile invocation:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Xml.XPath.XPathException:
>   XsltContext is needed for this query
>   because of an unknown function.    at
>   MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.CompiledXpathExpr.UndefinedXsltContext.ResolveFuncti
>   on(String prefix, String name,
>   XPathResultType[] ArgTypes)    at
>   MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.FunctionQuery.SetXsltContext(XsltContext
>   context)    at
>   MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.CompiledXpathExpr.SetContext(XmlNamespaceManager
>   nsM anager)    at
>   System.Xml.XPath.XPathExpression.Compile(String
>   xpath, IXmlNamespaceResolv er
>   nsResolver)

Anybody know the trick to use off-the-shelf XPath functions with XPathExpression.Compile?
Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**The function** [**`ends-with()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-ends-with) **is not defined for [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath)** **but only for [XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) and [XQuery](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/).**

You are using .NET. .**NET at this date does not implement** [**XPath 2.0**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/), [**XSLT 2.0**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/) or [**XQuery**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/).

One can easily construct an XPath 1.0 expression, the evaluation of which produces the same result as the function **`ends-with()`**:

**`$str2 = substring($str1, string-length($str1)- string-length($str2) +1)`**

produces the same boolean result (`true()` or `false()`) as:

**`ends-with($str1, $str2)`**

In your concrete case you just need to substitute the right expressions for **`$str1`** and **`$str2`**. They are, accordingly, **`/myXml/data`** and **`'World'`**.

**So, the XPath 1.0 expression to use, that is equivalent to the XPath 2.0 expression `ends-with(/myXml/data, 'World')` is**:

```
'World' = 
   substring(/myXml/data,
             string-length(/myXml/data) - string-length('World') +1
             )
```