# Parsing Hyperlinks from a webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written following code to parse hyperlinks from a given page.

```
    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    string html = web.DownloadString("http://www.msdn.com");
    string[] separators = new string[] { "<a ", ">" };
    List<string> hyperlinks= html.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(s =>
    {
        if (s.Contains("href"))
            return s;
        else
            return null;
    }).ToList();
```

Although string split still has to be tweaked to return urls perfectly. My question is there some Data Structure, something on the line of XmlReader or so, which could read HTML strings efficiently.

Any suggestion for improving above code would also be helpful.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: hi, just wondering: did you find any useful answers to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
        HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load("http://www.msdn.com");
        foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(link.GetAttributeValue("href", null));         
        }
```

this will print out every link on your URL.

if you want to store the links in a list:

```
 var linkList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
               .Select(i => i.GetAttributeValue("href", null)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a parser.  The most widely used one is [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).   Using that, you can interact with the HTML as a DOM.

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming you're dealing with well formed XHTML, you could simply treat
>   the text as an XML document. The framework is loaded with features to
>   do exactly what you're asking.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx

[Does .NET framework offer methods to parse an HTML string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473514/does-net-framework-offer-methods-to-parse-an-html-string/9473607#9473607)

Comment: When it is not feasible to install new tools, you have shown a good way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

refactored,

```
        var html = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.msdn.com");
        var separators = new[] { "<a ", ">" };
        html.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(s => s.Contains("href") ? s : null).ToList();
```