# PHP XPath ends-with

Tags: php, xpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use XPath function in a XPathExpression instance programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402211/how-to-use-xpath-function-in-a-xpathexpression-instance-programatically)

I'm trying to find all of the rows of a nested table that contain an image with an id that ends with '_imgProductImage'.

I'm using the following query:

```
"//tr[/td/a/img[ends-with(@id,'_imgProductImage')]"
```

I'm getting the error: **xmlXPathCompOpEval: function ends-with not found**

My google searches i believe say this should be a valid query/function. What's the actual function i'm looking for if it's not "ends-with"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

from [How to use XPath function in a XPathExpression instance programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402211/how-to-use-xpath-function-in-a-xpathexpression-instance-programatically/402357#402357)

> One can easily construct an XPath 1.0 expression, the evaluation of which produces the same result as the function `ends-with()`:
>
> `$str2 = substring($str1, string-length($str1)- string-length($str2) +1)`
>
> produces the same boolean result (`true()` or `false()`) as:
>
> `ends-with($str1, $str2)`

so for your example, the following xpath should work:

`//tr[/td/a/img['_imgProductImage' = substring(@id, string-length(@id) - 15)]`

you will probably want to add a comment that this is a xpath 1.0 reformulation of `ends-with()`.

Comment: @Alejandro see my comment to the question.

Answer (score 9):

It seems that [`ends-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-ends-with) is an XPath **2.0** function.

[**`DOMXPath`**](http://fr.php.net/domxpath) only supports XPath **1.0**

**Edit after the comment :** In your case, I suppose you'll have to :

- Find all images, using a simpler XPath query, that will return more images than what you want -- but include those you want to keep.
- Loops over those, testing in PHP, for each one of them, if the `id` attribute *(see the [**`getAttribute`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) method)* matches what you want.

To test if the attribute is OK, you could use something like this, in the loop that iterates over the images :

```
$id = $currentNode->getAttribute('id');
if (preg_match('/_imgProductImage$/', $id)) {
    // the current node is OK ;-)
}
```

Note that, in my regex pattern, I used a `$` to indicate *end of string*.

Comment: Is there a regex function or anything that i can use to get the same effect?

Comment: @Matt I've edited my answer with a couple more informations

Comment: See also [`registerPHPFunctions`](http://php.net/domxpath.registerphpfunctions) to perform the `preg_match` or other functions within the xpath

Comment: @Pascal, also note that PHP requires delimiters. `preg_match('/_imgProductImage$/' ...`

Comment: @Kevin oops, shame on me for having forgotten those :-( -- I'll edit right away, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 5):

There is no `ends-with` function in XPath 1.0, but you can fake it:

```
"//tr[/td/a/img[substring(@id, string-length(@id) - 15) = '_imgProductImage']]"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're on PHP 5.3.0 or later, you can use `registerPHPFunctions` to call any PHP function you want, although the syntax is a little odd. For example,

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xpath->registerPHPFunctions("ends_with");
$nodes = $x->query("//tr[/td/a/img[php:function('ends-with',@id,'_imgProductImage')]"

function ends_with($node, $value){
    return substr($node[0]->nodeValue,-strlen($value))==$value;
}
```

Comment: Some say that the code here would not be working (but they don't provide any further details so far either), in case you're interested, it's via here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19563167/367456