# PHP preg_match_all of parent with class name

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Using `preg_match_all` is it possible to match elements within a parent that has a specific class name?

For example I have this HTML markup:

```
<div class="red lorem-ipsum>
  <a href="#">Some link</a>
</div>

<div class="red>
  <a href="#">Some link</a>
</div>

<div class="something red lorem-ipsum>
  <a href="#">Some link</a>
</div>
```

Can I match each `<a>` that's within a parent with class name `red`?

I tried this but it does not work:

```
~(?:<div class="red">|\G)\s*<a [^>]+>~i
```

Comment: Use a parser...it will be easier, and more accurate.

Comment: DOMDocument is a much better way, use XPath (with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680721/php-dom-xpath-search-for-class-name).

Comment: @user3783243 parser?

Answer (score 2):

Use `DOMDocument` in combination with `DOMXPath`. Here the HTML is in the `$html` variable:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$matches = $xpath->query("//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' red ')]/a");
foreach($matches as $a) {
    echo $a->textContent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code!I have not tried `DOMXPath` before. Where am I selecting the `<a>`? is it the `/a` at the end?

Comment: Yes, indeed: `/` means "child" (`//` is "descendant"), and "a" is the tag name. The more complex part is to match a class. More about that part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath)