# How to get links with mp3 as extension

Tags: php, hyperlink, extract, preg-match-all

I have this code which extracts all links from a website. How do I edit it so that it only extracts links that ends on .mp3?
Here are the following code:

```
preg_match_all("/\<a.+?href=(\"|')(?!javascript:|#)(.+?)(\"|')/i", $html, $matches);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Use DOM and the following xpath: `//a[ends-with(@href, ".mp3")]` - it would be much easier I suppose :-)

Comment: @zerkms XPath, `ends-with` sounds much better than my answer! Didn't read your comment before

Comment: `$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc); $nodes = $xpath->query('//a[ends-with(@href, ".mp3")]');` -- add this as a second code to your answer then :-) (didn't test, too lazy atm)

Comment: @zerkms Did it. its cw now

Comment: @hek2mgl: I really like that `/@href` in the end

Comment: Thx. :) I really like XPath at all .... :)

Answer (score 3):

Update:

A nice solution would be to use [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) together with [XPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php), as @zerkms mentioned in the comments:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($yourHtml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc); 

// use the XPath function ends-with to select only those links which end with mp3
$links = $xpath->query('//a[ends-with(@href, ".mp3")]/@href');
```

---

Original Answer:

I would use DOM for this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($yourHtml);

$links = array();
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $elem) {
    if($elem->hasAttribute('href')
    && preg_match('/.*\.mp3$/i', $elem->getAttribute('href')) {
        $links []= $elem->getAttribute('href');
    }
}

var_dump($links);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer XPath, which is meant to parse XML/xHTML:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
@$DOM->loadHTML($html); // use the @ to suppress warnings from invalid HTML
$XPath = new DOMXPath($DOM);

$links = array();
$link_nodes = $XPath->query('//a[contains(@href, ".mp3")]');
foreach($link_nodes as $link_node) {
    $source = $link_nodes->getAttribute('href');
    // do some extra work to make sure .mp3 is at the end of the string

    $links[] = $source;
}
```

There is an [`ends-with()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435310/php-xpath-ends-with) XPath function that you can replace `contains()`, if you are using XPath 2.0.  Otherwise, you might want to add an extra conditional to make sure the `.mp3` is at the end of the string.  It may not be necessary though.