# DOM XPath queries fails

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

I have this code sample (full code 
[here](https://eval.in/504252)):

```
$raw = " ( xml data ) ";

$nsURIs = array
(
  'opf'     => 'http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf',
  'dc'      => 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/',
  'dcterms' => 'http://purl.org/dc/terms/',
  'xsi'     => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
  'ncx'     => 'http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/',
  'calibre' => 'http://calibre.kovidgoyal.net/2009/metadata'
);

$dom   = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML( $raw,LIBXML_NOBLANKS );

$metadata = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'metadata' )->item(0);         #metadata

$xpath = new \DOMXPath( $dom );
foreach( $nsURIs as $key => $ns ) $xpath->registerNamespace( $key, $ns );

$query = array();
$query[] = '//dc:identifier';                                          #00
$query[] = '//dc:identifier[. = "9780439554930"]';                     #01
$query[] = '//dc:identifier[@opf:scheme="ISBN"]';                      #02
$query[] = '//dc:identifier[starts-with(@opf:scheme,"I")]';            #03
$query[] = '//dc:identifier[contains(@opf:scheme,"SB")]';              #04
$query[] = '//dc:identifier[ends-with(@opf:scheme,"N")]';              #05 Unregistered
$query[] = '//dc:identifier["IS" = substring(@opf:scheme, 0, 2)]';     #06 Fails
$query[] = '//dc:identifier[contains(.,"439")]';                       #07
$query[] = '//dc:identifier[@*="ISBN"]';                               #08
$query[] = '//dc:date[contains(@*, "cation")]';                        #09
$query[] = '//dc:*[contains(@opf:*, "and")]';                          #10 Wrong Result
$query[] = '//dc:*[contains(@opf:file-as, "and")]';                    #11
$query[] = '//dc:*[contains(@opf:*, "ill")]';                          #12
$query[] = '//dc:contributor[@opf:role and @opf:file-as]';             #13
$query[] = '//dc:subject[contains(.,"anta") and contains(.,"Urban")]'; #14
$query[] = '//dc:subject[text() = "Fantasy"]';                         #15

for( $i=0; $i<count($query); $i++ )
{
  $result = $xpath->evaluate( $query[$i] );
  echo sprintf( "[%02d]  % 2d  %s\n", $i, $result->length, $query[$i] );
}
```

Query **#5** Fails due to unregistered function; query **#6** Fails (0 results insted of 1) and query **#10** generate 1 item instead of 2 (as properly generated at following query **#11**).
Same results performing query on `$metadata`context.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435310/php-xpath-ends-with) I have found an alternative to unregistered `ends-with`:

```
$query[] = '//dc:identifier["N" = substring(@opf:scheme, string-length(@opf:scheme) - string-length("N"))]';
```

but even this hack fails...

Anyone have suggestion or alternatives?

Comment: What is the question exactly? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My achieve is to check if XPath works fine. The question is: fails in provided code are XPath bugs or because of my errors? In xml code there are two nodes with text 'and' in attribute named `opf:file-as`: why query 10 return 1 item (incorrect) and query #11 return 2 items (ok)? And the hack to bypass unregistered `ends-with` function (marked as working in cited question) is not correct? Or I have to forget `ends-with` queries? 
I'm sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: regarding `ends-with()` function, you should've read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402211/how-to-use-xpath-function-in-a-xpathexpression-instance-programatically/402357#402357) (answer to the duplicated question you linked to)

Comment: Yes, I had read (and linked too)... but I have forget the `+ 1` at the end! Thanks! 
(The problem with query **#10** remains unsolved).

Comment: Side notes: 1. XPath expressions that doesn't pose a problem is only distracting the reader, I'd suggest to remove it form your question. 2. Multiple questions is normally better posted separately : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts (consider these in your future questions).

Comment: Ok, Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding `#06 Fails` :**

```
//dc:identifier["IS" = substring(@opf:scheme, 0, 2)]
```

**Explanation :**

XPath index start from `1` instead of `0`, so the correct parameters of `subsstring()` here would be :

```
//dc:identifier["IS" = substring(@opf:scheme, 1, 2)]
```

**Regarding `#10 Wrong Result` :**

```
//dc:*[contains(@opf:*, "and")]
```

**Explanation :**

When passing multiple values as function parameter in XPath 1.0, only the first value would be evaluated. So in this case, only the first attribute with prefix `opf` will be evaluated, hence the following element doesn't count :

```
<dc:contributor opf:role="ill" opf:file-as="GrandPré, Mary">Mary GrandPré</dc:contributor>
```

to avoid this problem, you should change the XPath to be as follow :

```
//dc:*[@opf:*[contains(., "and")]]
```