# How to find an image tag by filename using xpath

Tags: xpath, cucumber, capybara

I am running some cucumber features using capybara and I need to check if a certain image is being shown.

I tried this xpath match but apparently the function `matches` is not available:

```
//img[matches(@src, "my_image.png")]
```

Comment: If it is shown on the page you are getting it or if you got it correctly and you need to check it ?

Comment: I would not call this an exact duplicate, but the answer is very familiar. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402211/how-to-use-xpath-function-in-a-xpathexpression-instance-programatically

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't need any `matches` function. Use:

```
//img[@src='my_image.png']
```

Or, if the path can include text before the portion you want to match:

```
//img['my_image.png'=substring(@src, string-length(@src) - 11)]
```

This second expression imitates an `ends-with` function.

If you don't like hard-coding the substring length, then use:

```
//img['my_image.png'=substring(@src, 
          string-length(@src) - string-length('my_image.png') + 1)]
```

For completeness: in some cases, the following is acceptable:

```
//img[contains(@src, 'my_image.png')]
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used contains since it wasn't an exact match.

Comment: Thanks. Been looking all over for a list of xpath functions capybara supports. I was banging my head trying to figure out why my ends-with matcher doesn't work. Do you have a list of supported functions?