# Can I exclude a specific file name with Wix Heat using transforms?

Tags: wix, installation, heat

Is it possible to exclude a specific file name with Wix using transforms?
I can exclude files that *contain* a certain string, but this excludes any file name matching the string. For example I can exclude file.exe with the following;

```
<xsl:key name="fileexe-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, 'file.exe')]" use="@Id"/>
```

but this will also exclude files with file.exe in their name, like file.exe.config.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you should use `ends-with` instead of `contains`. But `ends-with` does not exist in XSLT 1.0. :)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848780/use-ends-with-in-xslt-v1-0/11857166#11857166) gives enough details to get the idea of how to implement it. Basically it is a combination of `substring` and `string-length` functions.

Besides, you should also consider normalizing the casing before comparison. That is, it is better to lower-case (or upper-case) both strings - the original and the one it ends with. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/586273/274535) can give you an idea of how to do it.

Keeping all this in mind, you will end up with something similar to this:

```
<!-- The starting backslash is there to filter out files like 'abcfile.exe' -->
<!-- Besides, it's lower-cased to ease comparison -->
<xsl:variable name="FileName">\file.exe</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="ABC">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="abc">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="fileexe-search" match="wix:Component[translate(substring(wix:File/@Source, string-length(wix:File/@Source) - string-length($FileName) + 1), $ABC, $abc) = $FileName]" use="@Id"/>
```

Comment: You answer set me on the right path. For some reason whenever I used a variable I got an error;
`heat.exe : error HEAT5055 : Error applying transform exclude.xsl to harvested WiX: Variables cannot be used within this expression.` 
So I replaced the variable with the actual filename. For my exclusion I am guaranteed the case of the filename so I didn't implement the case comparison. 
`<xsl:key name="fileexe-search" match="wix:Component[translate(substring(wix:File/@Source, string-length(wix:File/@Source) - string-length('\file.exe') + 1), $ABC, $abc) = '\file.exe']" use="@Id"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer provided by @Yan works I prefer to use C# which is simpler to use.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    ...
    xmlns:my="urn:my-installer">
    ...

<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="my">
<msxsl:using namespace="System.IO" />
<![CDATA[
public bool EndsWith(string str, string end)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    return false;

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(end))
    return false;

  return str.EndsWith(end);
}
]]>
</msxsl:script> 

    ...
```

Usage example:

```
<xsl:key name="ignored-components-search" match="wix:Component[my:EndsWith(wix:File/@Source, '.pssym')                                                   
                                               or my:EndsWith(wix:File/@Source, '.pdb')
                                               or my:EndsWith(wix:File/@Source, '.cs')
                                               or my:EndsWith(wix:File/@Source,'.xml')                                                      
                                                 ]" use="@Id" />
```

Comment: thanks @derwasp, I went with @Yan's answer as I couldn't figure out how to enable script execution using heat. I kept getting `heat.exe : error HEAT5055 : Error applying transform exclude.xsl to harvested WiX: Execution of scripts was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableScript property to enable it. `. I'm sure this would have worked just fine if I could have figured that out.