# Equivalent to (.*) in XPath

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I am trying to find an equivalent to (.*) from regexes in XPath. Now this is what I currently have:

I have an HTML a-tag with an href to `world/nl44/town/ANYNUMBER` where `ANYNBUMBER` So it could for example be: `world/nl44/town/12345` and `world/nl44/town/1232` is replaced by a random value (I just need the value of the a tag).

The query would look something like this:

`$elements = $xpath->query('//a[@href="/world/nl44/town/ANYNUMBER"]');` With ofcourse `ANYNUMBER` replaced by the XPath equivalent of (.*)

To sum it up:

`<a href="/world/nl44/town/12344">Something</a>` <- This is what my a looks like, where 12344 could be any number, and I just need the value between the tags, so with this example I would want it to return "Something".

How would I go about this?

Comment: Did you try `world/nl44/town/*`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I used alexce's solution, which works flawlessly.

Comment: That's great, just saying, `*` is the closest equivalent to `.*` in regex.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: You're probably thinking about `*` in an XPath matching any element.  L Ja instead is trying to match any character within a string here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`starts-with()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with):

```
//a[starts-with(@href, "/world/nl44/town/")]
```

Answer (score 0):

### XPath 2.0

XPath 2.0 has [String Functions that Use Pattern Matching](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#string.match) where `.*` itself will work:

- [`matches()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches)
- [`replace()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace)
- [`tokenize()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize)

So in XPath 2.0, you can use:

```
//a[matches(@href, '/world/nl44/town/.*')]
```

### XPath 1.0

XPath 1.0 has no support for regex-based pattern matching, only basic string functions.  While `.*` has no direct equivalence, it's sometimes possible to use [`starts-with()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with) (see [@alecxe's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36552574/290085) in this particular case, +1), [`contains()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains), or the other XPath 1.0 [String Functions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions) to disregard parts of a string to achieve similar results to matching `.*`.  As another example, the start of a string can be disregarded via a [clever combination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11857166/290085) of [`substring()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring), [`string-length()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string-length), and string equality checking, effectively implementing `ends-with()`-like functionality.