# xpath select all attributes ending with foo?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Is it possible with XPATH/XSLT 1.0 to select all attributes ending with "Foo"?

I'm writing some XSLT to get the list of all values of all attributes for all "InterestingElement"s where the attribute name ends with "Foo".

Actually I also want to filter out those where the value is empty `""`

I tried specifying a stylesheet for XSLT 2.0 but got `xsl:version: only 1.0 features are supported`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
            xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes">
```

So far I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="//InterestingElement">
<xsl:value-of select="__what goes here?__"/><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:text>end</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here's some sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <Other Name="Bob"/>
  <InterestingElements>
    <InterestingElement AttrFoo="want this"
                        Attr2Foo="this too"
                        Blah="not this"
                        NotThisFoo=""/>
  </InterestingElements>
</root>
```

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: can you also share `xml` sample, desired output and code you've already tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### XPath 1.0 Solution

`string-join` and `ends-with` are XPath 2.0. For 1.0, you can use the following, which returns all the values separated by space:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//InterestingElement/@*['Foo' = substring(name(.), string-length(name(.)) - string-length('Foo') +1) and . != '']">
  <xsl:value-of select="." /><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

To get the matching attribute names instead of values, change the select to `select="name(.)"`

Based on [kjhughes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290085/kjhughes) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42912729/2261424) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848780/use-ends-with-in-xslt-v1-0).

Comment: @user3735178 I forgot that string-join is XSLT 2.0 ... I edited my answer to put it in a `<xsl:for-each>` instead.

Comment: Possibly `<xsl:value-of select="node()" /><xsl:text> </xsl:text>` or `<xsl:value-of select="node()/" /><xsl:text> </xsl:text>`, but I'm not 100% sure of that.

Answer (score 4):

### XPath 2.0 Solution

XPath 2.0 alone can solve this; in XSLT 2.0, no `xsl:for-each` is needed -- just `xsl:value-of`.

This XPath,

```
string-join(//InterestingElement/@*[ends-with(name(.), 'Foo') and . != ''], ' ')
```

will return a space-separated list of the (non-empty) values of all `InterestingElement` attributes whose name ends with `Foo`.

Comment: or you could also eliminate the `string-join()` and use the `@separator`: `<xsl:value-of select="//InterestingElement/@*[ends-with(name(.), 'Foo') and . != '']" separator=" "/>`

Comment: @MadsHansen: Good idea.