# preg_match_all and regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i have page in that approx 10-15 links are there and all links are in my control and end with some words like celebrity i want to filter all links ending with that word so i have written this

```
    $regex='|<a.*?href="(.*_celebrity)"|';


    preg_match_all($regex,$result21,$parts);
$links=$parts[0];
foreach($links as $link){
{
    echo $link."<br>";
    mysql_query ("INSERT INTO tablea(linkssas) VALUES ('$link')");
    }
```

it does the job and filters all links which is ending with _celebrity but the output is not entering in database.all links are entering in one row  and it is not plain it is in the form of anchor text but i want  plain links in the database as i am using foreach so all links should be entered in seperate row but all rows are entering in single row and in the form of anchor like `http://xyz.com/edje/jjeieied_celebrity">A</a>`

but i want only links in database

Comment: You should not use a regex to get the links, but DOMDocument instead. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Sounds like a problem with a greedy regex.  Really you want `href="(.*?_celebrity)"`, but _really_ you are better off using a proper DOM parser like DOMDocument or SimpleXML for this.

Comment: This sounds like a job for Tony The Pony..... Or better yet, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), it's a good explaination about why you shouldn't try to parse HTML using regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I felt obliged to give you the [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/domdocument) tour:

```
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($result21);

$suffix = "_celebrity"; $suffix_len = strlen($suffix);

foreach ($d->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    if ($href && substr($href, -$suffix_len) === $suffix) {
        // do your insert here
    }
}
```

Or, using [`XPath`](http://www.php.net/domxpath) instead of `getElementsByTagName`:

```
$xp = new DOMXPath($d);

foreach($xp->query('//a[substring(@href, string-length(@href) - 9) = "_celebrity"]') as $node) {
    echo $node->getAttribute('href');
}
```

And here's a message from our chat room:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: And do the insert with PDO using bindParam

Comment: Or maybe better even xpath: [How to use XPath function in a XPathExpression instance programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402211/how-to-use-xpath-function-in-a-xpathexpression-instance-programatically)

Comment: @jack not working i am trying this added few lines to echo    $op7=''.$link->getAttribute('href').'';
  echo $op7;

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to loop through $parts[1] instead of $parts[0].

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: I had to modify the regex, but this is bad practice to use a regex in that case. This is also bad practice to use mysql_query()