# selenium ide Contains or Starts-with for revit

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

How to write Contains or Starts-with for the following dinamyc revit id?

```
id=revit_form_Button_55_label
```

or

xpath attribute as following:

```
//span[@id='revit_form_Button_55_label']

<span id="revit_form_Button_67_label" class="dijitButtonText" dojoattachpoint="containerNode">Yes</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the below examples

1) `"//a[contains(.,'continue')]"`

2)`"//div[starts-with(@class,'bdyItmPrt')and contains(.,'Registration Information Entered by User:')]"`

Comment: Looks like you are not including @id. Can you write it using my info so I could try it?

Comment: //div[starts-with(@id,'revit_form_Button_55_label')and contains(.,'Yes')]" Try This.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you:

```
//span[starts-with(@id, 'revit_')]
```

This adds class to the selector:

```
//span[starts-with(@id, 'revit_')][@class='dijitButtonText']
```

Comment: its valid but its not clicking on the button. Can we add class it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `starts-with()` plus `ends-with()` function :

```
//span[starts-with(@id, 'revit_form_Button_') and ends-with(@id, '_label']
```

Or if `ends-with()` is not available in your platform, you can replace it with snippet [by @DimitreNovatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/402357/2998271) :

```
substring($str1, string-length($str1)- string-length($str2) +1)
```

So the entire XPath would be like :

```
//span[
        starts-with(@id, 'revit_form_Button_') 
            and 
        substring(@id, string-length(@id)- string-length('_label') +1)
      ]
```

Comment: I tried with the snippet its valid but its not clicking on the button. Can we add class it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked: //span[starts-with(@id, 'revit_form_Button_') and contains(.,'Yes')][@class='dijitButtonText']